# determining validity of the regression

Tags: multiple-regression, cross-validation, bootstrap, reliability

I have performed curvilinear regression analyses on my data and the curvilinear fit is better than the linear (as determined by the F-stat of anova). I am now searching for a way to measure the reliability of my findings. The sample size is not large enough to do cross-validation (n=60). I was thinking of bootstrapping my results, but wonder whether there are other ways to assess the reliability of these models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some standard error metrics to consider are L2 error, L1 error, RMS, and Pearson/Spearman correlation. Bootstrapping is a good idea, but if possible check if the variance isn't too high as compared to the population. If it's a high variance and/or your data is high dimensional, then reliability is hard to trust, even with bootstrapping.

With a small data set, consider using leave-one-out cross validation. Another suggestion is to use a [Gaussian process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) for your regression, assuming you have continuous features. Not only does it work well for relatively small data sets, it's also a Bayesian model that can output a distribution for each prediction, so you can obtain uncertainty estimates as well.